# How to change background colour of legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Does anybody know how to change the background colour for the points legend in ggplot2. I have created the plot below and would like to change the white background on the legend? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: add `+ theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "black"))` to your call

Comment: Late to the party, but please add `+ coord_quickmap()`!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `legend.key` parameter of `theme`. From `?theme`:

> `legend.key`: background underneath legend keys (`element_rect()`; inherits from `rect`)

That is

`theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "black"))`

An example:

```
a <- seq(1:5)
b <- seq(1:5)
c <- seq(1:5)
d <- data.frame(a, b, c)
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = a, y = b, color = factor(c))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "yellow"))
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Hi, how can increase the legend color keys(dots)?