# R ggplot2 change background color of *specifically* linetype legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a similar question, but the solution does not work for `scale_linetype_manual`:
[Similar but not the same SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826156/how-to-change-background-colour-of-legend-in-ggplot2).
When I use the `legend.key` parameter it only inserts a element_rect *behind* the lines in my scale. (See pictures below)

I have everything working on my graph now except that my graph has a white background and scale_linetype_manual is inserting a grey background.

[image]

When I use the `legend.key` parameter this is what I get (I set it to black so it would be visible, i.e., `legend.key=element_rect(fill="#000000")`):

[image]

As you can see, it is adding a black rectangle *behind* the grey one.

How can I change the color of the grey rectangle?

Here is the ggplot2 code:

```
p = ggplot()+
    theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "#FF00FF"), 
          axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "#FF00FF"),
          axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "#FF00FF"), 
          axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "#FF00FF"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",color="black"),
          legend.key=element_rect(fill="#000000"))+

    geom_rect(data=df2, mapping=aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax,fill=color),show.legend = T)+
    scale_fill_manual(name="Codon type",values=c('#FFEBCC','#E6FFF7','#F2F2F2'),
                      labels=c("CR","NCR","None"),
                      limits=c("CR","NCR","None"))+

    #-----This should be the relevant part-----
    geom_path(data=df,aes(x=resseqnum,y=y.sec,color='b',linetype='b'))+
    geom_path(data=df,aes_string(x='resseqnum',y='cen',color='a',linetype='a'),size=.5)+
    geom_path(aes(x=c(x.min,x.max),y=c(a,a),color='c',linetype='c'))+
    scale_linetype_manual(name="Lines",values=c("a"='solid',"b"='solid',"c"='dotted'),
                          labels=c('Centrality','Minmax','Zero reference'))+
    scale_color_manual(name="Lines",values=c('#00FF00','#FF00FF','#FF00FF'),
                       labels=c('Centrality','Minmax','Zero reference'))+
    #-----Possible end of relevant part-----    

    scale_y_continuous("Centrality",sec.axis=sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b,name="Minmax"))+
    scale_x_continuous("Sequence location")+
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,10))+

    ggtitle("Title")
```

For reproducibility:

df.txt

```
resseqnum,cen,y.sec
1,4,3
2,5,6
3,6,3
4,NA,NA
5,NA,NA
6,6,4
7,3,2
8,1,3
9,5,3
10,10,5
```

df2.txt

```
xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,color
1,2,1,10,CR
5,7,1,10,NCR
9,10,1,10,None
```

Other:

```
b=2.25
a=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "#000000")))
```

To your plot, then you'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Good heavens, thank you! I had stumbled on this documentation, https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html but couldn't for the life of me figure out how to apply it.