# How can I change the background in a ggplot legend for a line aesthetic without changing other backgrounds?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-sf

I'm making a map with `sf` in `ggplot2` with two sets of lines. One set of lines has a column of values that I'm matching to the "color" aesthetic. The other set of lines I want to all be white (the background of the map is black).

I want the legend to show the white line on a black background, as well as to show the colored lines with a white background. It seems that element_rect can only go in the theme section, not guides/override.aes.

**How can I have a white line running through a black box for the "lines2" geometry, but a white background for the "lines1" geometry?**

Reproducible code:

```
library(sf)
library(geosphere)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

a<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[1:10,]))
b<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[91:100,]))

c<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[21:30,]))
d<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[81:90,]))

lines1<-gcIntermediate(a,b,sp = TRUE)
lines1<-st_as_sf(lines1)
lines1$col <- rep(c("A","B"),5)
lines2<-gcIntermediate(c,d,sp = TRUE)
lines2<-st_as_sf(lines2)

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nc,fill = 'black',color = 'white')+
  geom_sf(data = lines1,aes(color = col))+
  geom_sf(data = lines2, color = 'white',aes(linetype = "help"))+
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill="black"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred","yellow"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = c(4))))
```

Here's what I have:

[image: Current code results]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Comment: You might try phrasing title as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

This is basically the same solution as @JavierMtzRdz posted (+1)

---

### Original answer:

I wasn't able to get a working solution using `guides()` or `theme()`, so you may need to resort to a custom `key_glyph()` for this use-case, e.g.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(geosphere)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

a<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[1:10,]))
#> Warning: st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries
b<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[91:100,]))
#> Warning: st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries

c<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[21:30,]))
#> Warning: st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries
d<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc[81:90,]))
#> Warning: st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries

lines1<-gcIntermediate(a,b,sp = TRUE)
lines1<-st_as_sf(lines1)
lines1$col <- rep(c("A","B"),5)
lines2<-gcIntermediate(c,d,sp = TRUE)
lines2<-st_as_sf(lines2)

# Create a custom key_glyph function:
draw_key_custom <- function(data, params, size) {
  gp = grid::gpar(
    col = "white",
    fill = "black",
    lwd = 3,
    lty = 1
  )
  grid::grobTree(
    grid::rectGrob(width = 1, height = 1),
    grid::linesGrob(x = c(0.2,0.8), y = 0.5),
    gp = gp
  )
}

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nc,fill = 'black',color = 'white')+
  geom_sf(data = lines1, aes(color = col))+
  geom_sf(data = lines2, color = 'white', aes(linetype = "help"),
          key_glyph = draw_key_custom)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred","yellow")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = 3)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! I saw the custom key_glyph solution somewhere else but didn't quite know how to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that the best way to do that is overriding the fill legend (like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408024/r-ggplot2-change-background-color-of-specifically-linetype-legend)), but it seems that it does not work with `geom_sf`. Consequently, I would change the key_glyph function.

```
# Here, I determine how the legend is going to be displayed
my_key <- function(data, params, size) {
  grid::grobTree(
    draw_key_rect(data, list()),
    grid::segmentsGrob(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5),
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour %||% "grey20",
      fill = data$fill %||% "white",
      lwd = (data$size %||% 0.5) * .pt,
      lty = data$linetype %||% 1
    )
  )
}

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc,
          fill = 'black',
          color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = lines1,
          aes(color = col))+
  geom_sf(data = lines2, 
          aes(lty = "help"),
          key_glyph = my_key, # Here, I used the new key function
          fill = "black",
          color = 'white') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred","yellow"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = c(4))))
```

As a result, I got this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! What is the "%||%" operator? My R is somewhat out of date and it seems like that's not actually google-able.

Comment: It is part of the {rlang} package. It is charged when you use {tidyverse}. It says that if the element on the left equals NULL, it should use the element on the right.